# Duplicate cursor so it appears twice

Tags: css, cursor, double, mouse

I would like to know if there is a way to duplicate the cursor in my website so it appears twice, say as if you are seeing it drunk. I would like it to keep being responsible to images and change, but always double... is it possible to do this in an easy way? my CSS is pretty basic... thanks in advance!

This is an example: https://s11.postimg.org/ba76nmrvn/cursor_1.png

Answer (score 0):

You can make some image and define it as cursor like this:

```
body {
    cursor: url(path/to/your-arrows.png);
}
```

Doesn't need to be the body, you can define this for any HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

You can load custom images, but don't forgot to *always specify a generic cursor at the end of the list, in case none of the URL-defined cursors can be used*

```
body {
    cursor:url(double-arrows.png),url(anotherCursor.cur),auto;
}
```